Formatting an XSLT to add a * into a number
Fairly new to XSLT format and trying to have it output 2 numbers based on 1 input.
I've tried a few things and it hasn't been working.
Lets say that it gets 8989 from telephoneNumber as it's linked to LDAP.
I want one output as 8989, which I get.
I need another that is 8*989, so the XSLT file needs to insert a * as the second digit.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
For the single output, this works:
    <Extension>
        <xsl:value-of select="telephonenumber"/>
    </Extension>

So for multi I guess I need the below with the adaptation of the number to include the * where the #*### is?
    <xsl:for-each select="telephoneNumber">
    <Extension>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:value-of select="#*###"/>
        </Extension>
    </xsl:for-each>

Thanks,
Scutch

Use XPath functions like substring and concat or for current versions like XSLT 3 replace(telephonenumber, '^[0-9]', '$0*').

Thanks, I'll try and read into it and figure it out,

Please provide a reproducible example, including the XML input and the expected output - see: [mcve]. Also state which version of XSLT your processor supports (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153).

Please clarify if the input is always exactly 4 digits and if not, what should be the result then.

So the input is a field from LDAP so would always be just a 4 digit number, e.g. 8989

This is part of a software that is pulling user information from AD, so I can't run the command linked to see an output on version.

If you can write your own XSLT stylesheet then you can include the code to output the version. Otherwise what is this question about?

I mapped the version and processor to text fields to see the output.
What I got was:
Apache Software Foundation (Xalan XSLTC)
Version: 1.0

After much trial and error this worked in my scenario, adding both the telephone number e.g. 8989, and the transformed extension 8*989 as a separate extension.
<Extensions>
    <Extension>
        <xsl:value-of select="telephonenumber"/>
    </Extension>
    <Extension>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat((substring(telephonenumber,1,1)),'*',(substring(telephonenumber,2,3)))"/>
    </Extension>
</Extensions>

